# Poorly defined member function

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I am running the following on an online compiler as part of the quiz. The code works fine and generates expected output however I am not able to pass through all the testing conditions. The compiler generates an error at the last test. I have rechecked all the spellings but couldn't find any logical error.

**Problem Description**

Assume the class member attributes 'username' is set as 'Admin' and password is set us '123'.  Then, first, the login function validates the username and password. If login is successful, then withdraw(amount) ask the user amount, to withdraw,

*condition-1:* if the amount to withdraw is greater than 20000 then display a message as “In-sufficient funds to withdraw“ and return 'False'.

*Condition-2:* If the amount to withdraw is less than 20000 then allow the amount to withdraw

**Bug/Error:**

The class method 'withdraw(amount) is not defined properly. Check the name of the function, balance variable name and the function logic.

**Working Code**

```
class SavingAccount:
    balance = 20000
    username = ""
    password = ""

    def __init__(self,username,password):
        self.username=username
        self.password=password

    def login(self,username,password):
        if self.username == username and self.password == password:
            return True
        else:
            print("Invalid username or password")
            return False

    def withdraw(self, amount):
        if amount > self.balance:
            print("In-sufficient funds to withdraw")
            return False
        elif amount <= self.balance:
            self.balance = self.balance - amount
            return True

sobj=SavingAccount("Admin","123")
username = input("Enter your name to Login ")
password = input("Enter password ")
login = sobj.login(username,password)

if(login == True):

    amount = int(input("Enter amount to withdraw"))

    withdrawl = sobj.withdraw(amount)

    if withdrawl == True:
        print(amount,"is withdrew")
        print(sobj.balance,"balance amount")
```

This question is available on a private server of my institute, therefore I am attaching the screenshot of code and output.
[image: Description]
[image: Expectation]
[image: Evaluation]

Comment: Do you know what the last test is? For instance, if you knew what the buggy input was, then you could step through that specific test case and see what's happening. Is the thing you're building this on public? If so, a link might help us see if there's something you're missing. I agree that your code seems to match the specifications based on some quick testing.

Comment: Actually this is on a private server. I have edited the post and have added the screenshot of the entire question. I only got the failed test case message as shown in the above picture.

Comment: I think the amount that StackOverflow can help you is probably limited; are you able to contact whoever it is who wrote the testcases? (A professor, a teacher, support for an online learning class?) They might be able to help more, and know what they're looking for more clearly

Comment: The instructions say the result for insufficient funds should be worded "In-sufficient" - but the third sample output doesn't have that hyphen.  Try it that way in your code, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced attribute call inside the `withdraw()` and it solved the problem.

Here is the solution/updated `withdraw()`-

```
def withdraw(self,amount):
    if amount > SavingAccount.balance:
        print("In-sufficient funds to withdraw")
        return False
    elif amount <= SavingAccount.balance:
        SavingAccount.balance = SavingAccount.balance - amount
        return True
```

I guess using `SavingAccount.balance` in place of `self.balance` is more elegant.